# Saving and loading an apps sql database

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I'd like to create a routine for the user to save their current version of my app's sqlite database into an app-specific folder in NSDocumentsDirectory, and then to generate a file list of saved sql files and load one of the file list (including the default file) as the working  sql version. I'm reasonably familiar with core data, but this is my first foray into file archiving and retrieval. I've seen topics which cover saving NSData, but not Core Data SQL files. How do I do it?

Marcin - thanks.  So if I have a UITextfield called fninput, is it like this?

```
NSString *path; 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inControl"]; 
NSString *filename = [fninput.text stringByAppendingString:@".sql"]; 
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]; 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

Comment: CoreData database is just a file so you can copy it as you would any other file.

Comment: Also, if I load a file, how do I get the app to cleanly switch from the current sql database to the one that's just been loaded?

Comment: I haven't done it myself but you will need to remove the current persistent store from your NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and add a new one. You should also make sure you're not using objects from the previous store and that your MOCs are associated with the new persistent store.

Comment: Thanks Marcin - good points.